# How to handle Two's complement Overflow in Binary representation

Tags: assembly, binary, boolean-logic, twos-complement

[image]In this link, I am looking at CMU's Computer Science review materials.

```
x = 30
y = -29
```

How do we handle overflow from binary addition?
I thought I understood but here's what I got when I added two, to 30.

```
Two's Complement 30 representation:

0001 1100 x = 30

x+2 = 32

  0001 1110 
+ 0000 0010
------------
  0010 0000
```

Is this not equal to 32, positive?
The answer key says x + 2 = -32, and while it indicates that there's overflow, I'm not sure where I can make this jump in logic/assume that it's going to be negative.

Please explain to me where this reasoning comes from/where I am going wrong. Thanks!

EDIT: Picture seems to be gone from Link.

Comment: Do you understand how 2-complement works? Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement, for examlpe (there is also section "Why it works" there)?

Comment: I don't really understand how we can say that the Hex Representation is 0x20, if it's a positive number. That would seem to indicate to me that it would at least be 0x80 number, as the leading bit would need to be a 1 in order for Two's Complement to be negative.

Comment: @SergGr I understand Two's Complement, which is why I'm a little confused as to how we can go from a bit at 30 to negative at 32, aren't we supposed to rollover at the largest/most significant bit? So if we add two, we're still within a positive range. x + 2 would not cause overflow.

Comment: Obviously from the way `y` is represented, in this task nubmers are stored in 6-bit containers rather than more typical today 8-bit bytes.

Comment: @SergGr How does a six bit container effect the calculations? Does it change the multiples of our bits or does it just change when we overflow?

Comment: In 2-complements the highest bit represents sign. So if 6-th bit in 6-bit container is 1, it means the value is negative. Bonus question: `y=-29` (hex=0x23), what is `y-5`?

Comment: @SergGr  If y = -29, the Binary representation is 100 011. y-5 = 110 111 100, I think. That was quick math. Point being the most sig. bit is the 9th position?

Comment: Since you say `110 111 100` it looks like you are working in a 9-bit container, but what about 6-bit container? Bonus question, if for -29, the Binary representation is 100 011 why it is negative at all?

Comment: @SergGr y-5 is some grossly large number; 0000 1111 1101 1110 And For your second question, If we have a six bit container, if 100 011 is the binary representation, then the sixth bit is the most significant, giving us -32 + 2 + 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136718/discussion-between-serggr-and-whatamia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of two's compliment appears to be correct. Assuming 8 bits, 30 + 2 should be 32 as you state. However, if we assume 6 bits we get the answers that the table provides.

```
  01 1110
+ 00 0010
---------
= 10 0000
```

Since the leading bit differs from the two operands (and we're performing addition of two positive numbers), an overflow has occurred and the answer is -32.